# In JavaScript why 2 > 1 > 0 true while 8 > 1 > 1 false?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

As we know about the greater than and less than operator that how they work.

```
    console.log(2 < 12) // true
    
    console.log(2 < "12") // true

    console.log("2" > "12") // true
```

But when we compare more than 2 values with greater than and less than operator. Then I can't understand the logic behind the scene.

```
    1. console.log(1 > 2 < 3) // true      and     console.log(1 > 2 > 3) // false

    2. console.log(9 > 2 > 9 < 8 < 9) // true
    
    3. console.log(9 > 8 > 7 > 9 > 5) // false
```

Can somebody please elaborate and explain behind the reason for 1 , 2 and 3 ?

Comment: You can only do comparisons between two values. Split the out and use the AND (&&) or the OR (||) operators

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you for your response and I understand your point but in log why I'm getting true for 2 and false for 3 ? That is the confusion .

Comment: it evaluates beginning from left to right, 1>2 is false which is zero and zero is less than 3 which gives true for the console.log(1 > 2 < 3) example

Comment: The last evaluation of `2.` is `true < 9` for `3.` it’s `false > 5`.

Comment: Thanks @charly1212 I got your point with the below logic. Correct me if I'm wrong .

9 > 2 = 1 > 9 = 0 < 8 = 1 < 9   for 1 

9 > 8 = 1 > 7 = 0 > 9 = 0 > 5   for 2

Comment: There's no operator for "comparing more than 2 values" in JS (and in many other languages). That's several separate compares between result of previous compare and next number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to clear this problem using following example.

```
1 < 2 < 3 // evaluates to true
```

But

```
3 > 2 > 1 // evaluates to false
```

As we know js execute from left to right. Therefor, in first example when statement

```
1 < 2
```

is executed it evalutes to true. In programming true refers to 1 and false refers to zero. Then after executing the above statement we have true means 1. Now when this result is combined with next statement

```
true < 3
```

Then in short this statement means

```
1 < 3
```

because true refers to 1 in programming. Since 1 < 3 is true that's why we have the final result as true.

Coming to the next example 3 > 2 > 1 which evaluates to false because

```
3 > 2 // evaluates to true
```

Since above statement is true then in programming sense we got 1(true) and then by combining this result with next statement

```
true > 1 // evaluates  to false
```

The above statement is in short

```
1 > 1
```

Since 1 is not greater than 1 therefor it returns the final result to false.

```
3 > 2 = true
true > 1 = false
```

So finally we conclude that by programming sense both statement evaluates to different results but in sense of mathematics both are same. Its a interview question. Hopefully you understand this.

Please let me know if needs any other information. In other case, It might be accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for your valuable response, Now I understand the logic.

Comment: @BHUPENDRASINGH You are always welcome. Kindly mark this answer as accepted

Comment: *In programming true refers to 1 and false refers to zero* that may be a common convention, but in Javascript this has a name. It's called **type coercion**.